# DensityHistogram specify bins in x and y

Tags: plotting, histograms

I have difficulties with specifying bins in both "x" and "y" for a density histogram.

This code works, but uses Automatic bins:

```
data = Transpose@{RandomReal[{0, 1}, 10], RandomReal[{10, 20}, 10]}
DensityHistogram[data]
```

However, how can I specify the following bin ranges for x and y:

```
xbins = Range[0,1,.1]
ybins = Range[10,20,2.5]
```

The help is a bit confusing and googling didn't help much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DensityHistogram[data, {{xbins}, { ybins}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks @kglr, I tried DensityHistogram[data, {xbins, ybins}], but apparently an extra pair of braces was missing.